# Can I make Visual Studio recognize more than just two shortcut key sequences for a keyboard shortcut binding?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

Coming from a multi-platform background I'm now set to use Visual Studio 2012 and soon 2013 for windows development. Discovering the features I'm blown away how powerful it is compared to other IDE's I'm used to except in one area where I feel it is **extremely** limiting: keyboard shortcut binding.

As far as I can figure through documentation and online (it's difficult to search for this, hence coming to stackoverflow), I'm only capable of binding two keyboard shortcut combinations to an action in the IDE. For example:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Will comment the current selection in Visual Studio - C# whereas

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Will format the document.

Two well known IDEs that I've used for cross platform development, Eclipse and Qt Creator, each allow up to 4. I can bind key sequences such as

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>

to actions if I want, and I do. Is it possible to extend Visual Studio to allow at least as many key sequences through a addon-on or plugin, registry entry modifications within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know are only maximum 2 sequences allowed in Visual Studio 2012. You can check that when you open the Options in Visual Studio and open the Keyboard Settings.

I have checked that by using `Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C`, but i´m not allowed to add more.

[image]